# Broken DAG with MWAA (Airflow Managed Airflow) - psycopg2

Tags: airflow, psycopg2, mwaa

With Managed Airflow 2.0.2, my requirements.txt  looks like

### requirements.txt

Apache-airflow[postgres]
psycopg2-binary
botocore

When I try importing psycopg2, I get a broken DAG failing to recognize psycopg2

I already tried

### requirements.txt

Apache-airflow[postgres]
psycopg2
botocore

Even

### requirements.txt

Apache-airflow[postgres]
psycopg2
psycopg2-binary
botocore

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

For Airflow 2.0.2 in MWAA use this in your requirements.txt

```
psycopg2-binary==2.8.6
```